# built in control on a urdf model in gazebo

Tags: control, ros, gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
i built a urdf model of an inverted pendlum and spawned it in gazebo.
it looks as if there is buil in control on it like if it falls it will stand right up. how can i stop that control?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="pendelum"> 

  <link name="rod">
   <inertial>
     <mass value="0.001"/>
     <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
     
     <inertia ixx="0.00"  ixy="0"  ixz="0" iyy="0.00" iyz="0"    izz="0.00" />
     </inertial>

   <physics type="ode" update_rate="100">
     <gravity xyz="0 0 -9.8"/>
         <ode>
           <solver type="quick" dt="0.01" iters="100" sor="1.3"/>
          </ode>
    </physics>

   <visual>
     <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.02" length="1"/>
     </geometry>
   </visual>

 <collision>
     <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0"/>
     <geometry>
       <cylinder radius="0.02" length="1"/>
     </geometry>
   </collision>
  
 </link>
  
  <link name="cmass"> 
    <inertial>
      <mass value="10.0" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" /> 
      <inertia  ixx="0.1" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="10"  iyz="0.0"  izz="0.1" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>


  </link>

   <joint name="weld" type="fixed">
    <parent link="rod" />
    <child link="cmass" />
    
  </joint>

   <link name="wor"> 
    <inertial>
      <mass value="100000" />
      <!-- center of mass (com) is defined w.r.t. link local   coordinate system -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" /> 
      <inertia  ixx="1000.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="1000.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1000.0" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.0005" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.4 0.4 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    

<collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.0005" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.4 0.4 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

<joint name="floor" type="revolute">
   <parent link="wor" />
    <child link="rod" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
<limit upper="3.15" lower="-3.15" effort="1000.00" velocity="1000.00"/>
<joint_properties damping="0.1" friction="1.0" />
</joint>

 <gazebo>
    <controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager" plugin="libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
      <interface:audio name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager_dummy_iface" />
    </controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager>
  </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="cmass">
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="rod">
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="wor">
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>

   </robot>
```

any ideas?
Thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43039/built-in-control-on-a-urdf-model-in-gazebo/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess what you see is caused by the physics engine. Rod is connected by a joint to the world but it's pose seems to be right in the floor. Try placing it above the floor, i.e. it should not collide with the wor link.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-09-05**:
thanks i think it is working better